# How to print every key and value from a dictionary when the value is a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote this dictionary:

```
dict = {
    "Someone1": ['Random1', 'Random2', 'Random3'],
    "Someone2": ['Random1', 'Random2', 'Random3'],
    }
```

And I want to print it in a way that the output will be:

```
Someone1 Random1
Someone1 Random2
Someone1 Random3
Someone2 Random1
```

and etc.

I tried this:

```
for name in dict.keys():
    print(name, dict[name])
```

But the output is not what I wanted
What can I do?

Comment: So you know how to loop over a dictionary, but not how to loop over a list?

Answer (score 0):

You need another nested loop to iterate over `dict[name]`. Also, you can simplify the code by iterating over keys and values (a.k.a. `items`):

```
for name, herbs in dict.items():
    for herb in herbs:
        print(name, herb)
```